# how to locate a div tag generated by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have created a new tag by jQuery, and the code looks like this:

```
new_compare_item = $("<div/>");
new_compare_item.attr("id", "compare_item");
new_compare_item.attr("name", "compare_item");
new_compare_item.addClass("div_image");
new_compare_item.append($("<img/>")
.addClass("image")
.attr("src", "/compare/sites/default/files/add_item.jpg")
.attr("height", 50)
.attr("width", 50));

new_compare_item.append($("<span/>")
.addClass("remove_item")
.click(function(){
$(this).parent().remove();
}));
```

There is a click event which again removes the above generated div tag. The code is this:

```
$(".remove_item").click(function(){
var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
var remove_item_id = document.getElementById(id);
$("div#"+id).remove();
)};
```

But, it cannot find the newly created newly created div tag. I have also replaced this with javascript but no use. The thing is it cannot find the id of newly created div tag. How to solve it?

Comment: Div and span tags should be : $('<div>') & $('<span>')

Comment: You have syntax error `new_compare_item.append($("<span/>")` --> missing `)`

Comment: friends please ignore this **)};** i have wrongly typed it while making changes in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `$(".remove_item").click(function(){ /* CODE */}` use `$(".remove_item").live('click',function(){ /* CODE */}` deference between them you can see here [jQuery live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: my reputation is under 15 otherwise i would also have rated you :)

Answer (score 0):

See you syntax:

```
$("div#"+id).remove();
//Change to
$("#"+id).remove(); OR
$("div[id='"+id+"']").remove();
```

Comment: $("div#"+id).remove(); is working fine. The problem is it cannot locate the newly created div tag, or to be precise it cannot locate the id of newly created div tag.

Answer (score 0):

At first,

```
new_compare_item = $("<div/>");
new_compare_item.attr("id", "compare_item");
new_compare_item.attr("name", "compare_item");
new_compare_item.addClass("div_image");
new_compare_item.append($("<img/>")
.addClass("image")
.attr("src", "/compare/sites/default/files/add_item.jpg")
.attr("height", 50)
.attr("width", 50));

new_compare_item.append($("<span/>")
.addClass("remove_item")
.click(function(){
$(this).parent().remove();
}));        
$('body').append(new_compare_item);
```

works fine. I tested with jQuery v1.7.1

Second,

```
$(".remove_item").click(function(){
var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
var remove_item_id = document.getElementById(id);
$("div#"+id).remove();
)};
```

It is incorrect. should be `});` instead of `)};`. And you should use a `.live('click',function(){})` instead of `.click(function(){})` because you dynamically added a div to the DOM. See [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: i dont know my version of jquery. and sorry, that one is incorrect. when i made changes in my code while posting this question i have wrongly typed it.